# How to open the target of a symbolic link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I have a file `test_a.txt`:

```
12345
67890
12345
67890
```

Then, I create a symbolic link to the file:

```
> ln -s ./test_a.txt test_b.lnk
```

Now, I want to open the file, through its link, in a python script:

```
fa = open('test_a.txt', mode='rt')
print(len(fa.readlines()))
fb = open('test_b.lnk', mode='rt')
print(len(fb.readlines()))
```

The output:

```
5
1
```

So, the 2nd `open()` call opens the link and not the target file. How can I tell python to follow the link?

---

**UPDATE 1**: After looking around, I found the `os.readlink()` and `os.path.realpath()` that were supposed to resolve the given path (the name of the symlink) to its target. However, when trying this in my Cygwin bash terminal, I get the following error:

`OSError: [WinError 4390] The file or directory is not a reparse point: 'test_b.lnk'`

This seems to be a Cygwin-specific issue, which adds another layer of complexity to the question.

Comment: Please tell us the output of `uname -a` and `echo $CYGWIN`. Also, `ls -l test_?.*` and `python3 -V`. ( Confirm you are using the cygwin python3, not a windows python, as windows pythons will not recognize some cygwin soft links.)

Comment: `uname -a`: `CYGWIN_NT-10.0 4RK1Q32 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:08 x86_64 Cygwin`

Comment: `echo $CYGWIN`: "" (empty, not set)

Comment: @DougHenderson - I am definitely not running the Cygwin Python, but an installation of the Python 3.7 from the official Python website download, which, according to your comment, may be the root of the problem.

Comment: `ls -l test_?.*`: `-rwx------+ 1 XY+User(113533) 1162109 30 Sep 29 15:33 test_a.txt 
      lrwxrwxrwx  1 XY+User(113533) 1162109 10 Sep 29 14:58 test_b.lnk -> test_a.txt`